# ListView only renders after hot reload

Tags: react-native

I'm using redux, the ListView is subscribed, the console log message displays, but the screen doesn't update until after a hot reload.  Any idea why the ListView wouldn't draw the new Todo on the screen?

```
render() {
    var store = getStore();
    var todos = store.getState().todos;
    var dataSource = this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(todos);
    console.log("Rendering: ", jtodos);
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>Todos to do</Text>
          <ListView
            dataSource={dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderTodo}
            style={styles.listView}/>
         </View>
    );
}
```

I've also changed the code to

```
renderTodo(todo) {
    console.log("Render:", todo);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container} key={todo.id}>
            <View style={styles.details}>
              <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{todo.text}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
render() {
    var store = getStore();
    var todos = store.getState().todos;
    console.log("Rendering: ", todos);
    var dataSource = this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(todos);
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>Todos to do</Text>
            {todos.map(this.renderTodo)}
        </View>
    );
}
```

The console log shows ALL the todos, including the new one that does NOT show up until after a hot reload....

Why is the screen not displaying the todo?

```
Rendering:  [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
Render: Object {text: "fghf", id: 1, completed: false}
Render: Object {text: "fghfbhhg", id: 2, completed: false}
Render: Object {text: "fghfbhhggfjg", id: 3, completed: false}
Render: Object {text: "fghfbhhggfjg", id: 4, completed: false}
Render: Object {text: "fghfbhhg", id: 5, completed: false}
Render: Object {text: "fghfbhhgkkkk", id: 6, completed: false}
Render: Object {text: "f", id: 7, completed: false}
```

None of these show up on the display until a hot reload.  Any added after a hot reload don't show up until the next hot reload.

Comment: Strange. So everything renders except the last object right `(text: f, id: 7, ...)`?

Comment: Actually, nothing renders until the hot reload happens, then everything renders.  BUT the console shows them all rendering all the time.

Comment: What is `this.dataSource` referring to in your `render` method ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing with `react-native` for about 3-4 months and just got into using the `listview`. I believe you have to actually set the state instead of assigning it to a variable.

Try the below code as I'm not 100% sure if it will work or not.

```
render() {
    var store = getStore();
    var todos = store.getState().todos;
    // You need to actually set the state! 
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(todos),
    });
    console.log("Rendering: ", jtodos);
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>Todos to do</Text>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderTodo}
            style={styles.listView}/>
         </View>
    );
}
```

**edit**

Set the state inside componentWillReceiveProps or the appropriate react life cycle method

Comment: Nope, this won't work. You CANNOT use `setState` in the `render` method. Calling setState will re-render your component. Using it in `render` creates a kind of infinite loop :)

Comment: Ahh whoops! Set it in componentWillReceiveProps or the appropriate react life cycle method @G.Hamaide